# Ideal of $\text{End}_k V$ has certain form.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, ideals

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over field $k$ and $R = \text{End}_k V$. How do I see that any left ideal of $R$ takes on the form $Rr$ for some suitable element $r \in R$?

Comment: Could you articulate what you've tried, in an effort to better understand or better "see"... Are you looking for an intuitive argument?

Comment: My questions are not meant to offend you. The strictness of the site regarding the majority of question posted to the site, is conveniently forgotten allowing "anything goes" when it comes to questions arising from a more advanced level, relatively speaking.  And so, I am trying to main consistency in action on and application of the sites requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Since $R$ is a semisimple ring, every left ideal will split out like this: $R=L\oplus L'$. In this decomposition, $1=e+e'$ where $e\in L$ and $e'\in L'$.

It's an exercise to prove that $e^2=e$ and $(e')^2=e'$. (Really, $e'=1-e$.)

It's another exercise to show that $L=Re$. Just remember that the sum is direct.