# Splitting of left ideal in semisimple ring, idempotents.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, ideals

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over field $k$ and $R = \text{End}_k V$. How do I see that any left ideal of $R$ takes on the form $Rr$ for some suitable element $r \in R$?

Since $R$ is a semisimple ring, every left ideal with split like this: $R = L \oplus L'$. In this decomposition, $1 = e + e'$ where $e \in L$ and $e' \in L'$.

Why does $e^2 = e$ and $(e')^2 = e'$?

And why does $L = Re$?

Comment: Because $1^2=1$.

Comment: If you have a question about [the hint you got on another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1943929/29335) you should ask the author first, not crowdsource the work to everyone else. Someone might think you're trying to avoid doing any thinking of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $1=e+e'$, with $e\in L$ and $e'\in L'$. Then
$$
e=e(e+e')=e^2+ee'
$$
Note that $e^2\in L$ and $ee'\in L'$, so we have $e^2=e$ and $ee'=0$.

Now, take $x\in L$; then $x=x1=xe+xe'$; then $xe'\in L'$ forces $xe'=0$ and $x=xe\in Re$.

---

The key part is $R=L\oplus L'$, so for $x\in R$ there exist *unique* $l\in L$ and $l'\in L'$ such that $x=l+l'$.

Comment: @user373879 Any element of $R$ can be *uniquely* written as the sum of an element in $L$ and an element in $L'$.